# Apache2 Creating index.html file instead of following DocumentRoot

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

apache2 will not follow the document root.  Instead it creates an index.html file in var/www/
every time I goto store.test

apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName store.test
    ServerAlias store.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hub-store/web
    DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "/var/www/hub-store/web">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Really have no idea why
For my sanity hub-store is 755 all and owner group is www-data for all

Still write html files to /var/www/ dir

WHY?

Comment: In my 20+ years of using Apache, I have never seen it create a file. Have you ruled out the PHP system in `hub-store/web` creating it? 

Comment: I've never seen it happen too.  There is no index.html file in hub-store/web only index.php and I'm telling it to load that.  Wonder if php isn't running it so it creates a index.html file.

Comment: What is the content of the `.html` file that's created? Is it the default Ubuntu Apache page saying "It works" or something like that? Or is it something a little more application-specific?

Comment: it's blank, empty file.

Comment: Making some progress. I enabled ssl ( i guess it was dissabled ) but now its creating the index.html file in my web dir even though DocumentIndex is set to index.php

Comment: Are there any other config files that are active that may be interfering with the target site? Check in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. In your VHost config, you could replace `0.0.0.0:{port}` with `*:{port}`, but this shouldn’t be causing issues.

Comment: i'm at a loss then I try to curl to it from the same machine it still gives me a blank page not results... I'm loosing my mind.